# Option for printing more start-up messages

Tags: graph-databases, agens-graph

there

I posted this question to ask whether there is an option or a way to
turn on and off more start-up messages of AgensGraph.

I am looking for an answer because I can only see the message stating
"server starting" when the server is starting up with a default setting.

> [home]$ ag_ctl start
>
> server starting

Therefore, I cannot assure whether the server is up normally until I check
the process list using `ps -ef | grep postgres`.(plus manually check logfiles to
see what was going on during the start-up process if the server is not started properly.)

If someone can advise me how I can make the server to print more start-up messages out, it would be really helpful to me.